# Recognize if an arm is swinging/moving towards Kinect sensor or away from it

Tags: c#, opencv, kinect, emgucv, gesture-recognition

I am trying to figure out how to recognize if a person's arm is swinging/moving towards or away from the Kinect. I'm thinking it is much like a hit or punch towards the sensor.

The depth changes as the arm is going toward or away from the sensor, ***but how can this gesture be recognized***?

I'm using the Kinect for Windows (older version) and SDK 1.8. I have also looked at EMGU (C# wrapper for OpenCV).

Any help answering this question would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check and use [Tracking Users with Kinect Skeletal Tracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131025.aspx) and [Channel 9s tutorials](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectQuickstart).

1 . Start with a base position of the user.

[image]

2 . Save the positions of the arm joints (e.g. schoulder left, elbow left, wrist left and hand left).

3 . The saved positions of step 2 are your reference points. Use these to calculate a swing move (e.g. (handLeftNew.z-value < handLeftReference.z-value), so movement towards Kinect).

**Code sample**

```
// get the joint
Joint leftHand = skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft];

// get the individual points of the left hand
double lefttX = leftHand.Position.X;
double leftY = leftHand.Position.Y;
double leftZ = leftHand.Position.Z;
```